# Como adicionar ao build path uma pasta via maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, querydsl

Tenho uma aplicação utilizando Jhipster, para fazer queries adicionei o querydsl, configurei no maven para gerar as classes Q, essas classes estão sendo geradas no caminho: target/generated-sources

Só que esta pasta não esta no meu buildpath sendo assim o projeto fica "quebrado" no eclipse, sei que via eclipse eu posso ir nesta pasta e adicionar ao classpath da aplicação, porém gostaria de saber se tem como adicionar via maven, assim ficaria transparente para os demais desenvolvedores.

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Uma forma que descobri foi de executar o comando mvn eclipse:eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O goal `eclipse:eclipse` é capaz de gerar uma configuração válida para o Eclipse baseado no seu `pom.xml`. Basicamente o que ele faz é sobrescrever o arquivo `.classpath` do seu projeto.

O problema disso é que toda vez que alterar o `pom.xml` precisa executar o comando de novo e a compilação e execução executadas dentro do Eclipse geralmente não respeita todas as configurações do Maven, já que elas são executadas separadamente.

Integrar Maven no Eclipse é preferencialmente feito usando o plugin M2E, que é instalado no Eclipse e já vem no "Eclipse for Java EE". Este plugin configura reconhece alterações no Maven e consegue fazer as atualizações necessários no Eclipse. Ele também permite executar a auto-geração de código quando você salva suas classes, além de outras facilidades.

Se o M2E não adicionar as classes geradas no classpath automaticamente, é porque falta configurar o seu `pom.xml` usando o [`build-helper-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) para adicionar o diretório onde as classes são geradas. Veja [exemplos de uso na documentação](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Lembre-se de que o classpath do Eclipse e o classpath do Maven são coisas diferentes. Cuidado para não cair na armadilha de alterar o projeto do Eclipse manualmente e achar que está tudo bem. Num projeto Maven, o classpath do Eclipse é apenas algo que deve ser derivado da configuração do Maven e pode não reproduzir fielmente o classpath quando você executa o Maven por linha de comando.